# XAMPP : phpmyadmin is frozen?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I open phpmyadmin (I click on Admin on the XAMPP Panel), the site opens normally. On the right side it says `root@localhost`, but I don't have to enter a password, it just directly logs in.

The Problem is, that it is somehow frozen. I can't click on anything. There is just the start page which opens when you open phpmyadmin and then it stays there. No changes can be done. 
Where could be the problem there? I already tried reinstalling it but it didn't help.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: try restart apache and mysql

Comment: I tried all of this. Nothing changed. I use IE8 @Cagy79

Comment: remove all cache in browser. try

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/99571/stuck-on-login-phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you try another browser like Chrome or Firefox? IE8 is quite old.